# Is it possible to delete every post of a specific user from VBulletin?

Tags: sql, vbulletin

Is it possible in VBulletin to make invisible / delete every single post by an user? Is it possible from the interface or through a query on the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all posts and threads by a single user from the vBulletin interface.

1. Login to your `vBulletin Admin Panel`.
2. Expand the `Threads & Polls` menu.
3. Click on the `Prune` link.
4. Scroll to the bottom of the `Prune` page and enter the `User Name` of the user who's posts you'd like to remove.
5. And finally... click the `Prune Threads` button.

Remember to backup your database before doing the above as there isn't an undo!